# How do i choose a correct static ip4 adress in dhcpcd?

Tags: dhcp

So i wanted to set a permanent connection with my ethernet cable in the /etc/dhcpcd.conf file, and i wrote this:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.2.10/24
static_routers=192.168.0.1
```

I choose the ip randomly because i thought that it didn't matter, after i rebooted and checked my ip with ifconfig it showed inet 192.162.2.10 so i thought it worked, but now my router doesn't see my raspberry and when i try to ping goole.com it says 'Temporary failure in name resolution', what do i do?

Comment: Your router is in a different network from your Pi. If random didn't matter why are you trying to set up a static IP?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "correct static IP address". If you want it to work you need to supply details of the existing network, BUT you would be better to request one from your router.

Answer (score 1):

You assigned the IP address `192.168.2.10` to your ethernet interface, with 24 bits for the network. That means that the network mask for the subnet is `255.255.255.0`. In other words, the host in the subnet are `192.168.2.1` - `192.168.2.254`. For anything outside that range, it will need to go through a gateway. So, for example, the google DNS server is 8.8.8.8; to reach it, you will use the gateway.

Your gateway is `192.168.0.1`. That is outside the subnet. Therefore, this gateway is not directly reachable. That means that there is no way to get out of your subnet. So you can also not reach the DNS server, and therefore you have a failure in the name resolution.

Your router/gateway must be in the same subnet als your Pi. If you use, for example, `192.168.0.10/24`, the router is in the same subnet, and you will see the router.